# How to determine if SKSpriteNode is completely contained within another SKSpriteNode

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm working on a tangrams game where smaller shapes are placed into a larger shape. The win condition of the game is determined when enough smaller shapes are contained in the larger shape.

I'm wondering how to determine if one SKSpriteNode is completely contained within another SKSpriteNode.

I've looked around on Stack Overflow and on the documentation provided by Apple for Sprite Kit and haven't found a good solution.

Let me know what you think!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming container is the larger shape and shape is an individual shape, you can determine whether each shape is wholly contained within container as follows:

```
if (CGRectContainsRect(container.frame, shape.frame))
{
    //....
}
```

Repeat that for every shape.

Comment: Word. Thanks for the response! You answered my question perfectly but I'm looking for an answer to a slightly different question. Is there a way to determine if the physics body of an SKNode is completely contained in the physics body of another SKNode?

Comment: if they are both rects then CGRectContainsRect, circle in rect and circle in circle tests are also quite simple, I'd google them

Comment: Unfortunately they aren't rects. I've included a link to show you what I'm looking at. I'm trying to determine when one triangle is completely contained within another triangle. [Tangrams Game Example](http://imageshack.com/a/img547/8512/e79c.png)